# NaNs produced in qtukey output

Tags: r

The following code is not generating output for few values of n. Getting the following message: "In stats::qtukey(p = 0.5, nmeans = n, df = Inf) : NaNs produced."

Any possible fix?

```
min_Ptukey <- function(par, nmeans){
  abs(.5 - stats::ptukey(q = par, nmeans = nmeans, df = Inf))
}

d <- function(n) {
if (n  < 100) {
  stats::qtukey(p = .5, nmeans = n, df = Inf)
}else{
  stats::optimise(f = min_Ptukey, interval = c(1,20), nmeans=n)$minimum
}
}

const<-data.frame(rep(NULL,2))
for(n in 2:75)
{
const<-rbind(const,c(n,d(n)))
}
colnames(const) <- c("n","d")
print(const,digits=18)
```

Comment: It is based on the value for 'nmeans' ` stats::qtukey(p = 0.5, nmeans = 37, df = Inf)
[1] NaN`

Comment: `qtukey(p=0.5,nmeans=37,df=637)` gives a non-NaN value, df=638 is NaN.  `plot(qtukey(p=0.5, nmeans=37, df=100:800))` shows more regions of difficulty

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted in the comments by @akrun and @ben-bolker the `qtukey` algorithm is breaking down and producing the `NaN`s you're seeing.  Need to change one of the three parameters you're feeding it.

any of these three will work

```r
qtukey(p=0.506, nmeans=37, df=Inf)
qtukey(p=0.50, nmeans=36, df=Inf)
qtukey(p=0.50, nmeans=37, df=2:280)
```

there may be another implemetation but note that the doco for `qtukey` says *qtukey will be accurate to the 4th decimal place*.